# Jquery UI Close Dialog & Open New Dialog

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, dialog

The concept seems simple enough, yet i'm having a lot problems executing it.

I need to close the current dialog and open another. It does close the #imageModal, but does not open the #uploadModal.

Any suggestions?

Edit: Added the #uploadModal

```
$("#imageModal").dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    height: 500,
    width: 500,
    modal: true,
    closeOnEscape: true,
    resizable: false,
    buttons: {
        'Upload Image': function() {
            // CLOSE 1 DIALOG AND OPEN ANOTHER
            $(this).dialog('close');
            $('#uploadModal').dialog('open');

        },
        Cancel: function() {
            $(this).dialog('close');
        }
    },
    close: function() {
        $(this).dialog('close');
    }
});


$("#uploadModal").dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    height: 500,
    width: 500,
    modal: true,
    closeOnEscape: true,
    resizable: false,
    buttons: {
        'Upload Image': function() {


        },
        Cancel: function() {
            $(this).dialog('close');
        }
    },
    close: function() {
        $(this).dialog('close');
    }
});
```

Comment: can we see the HTML/JS for the #uploadModal? :)  Also, make sure that $(this) is not the button you clicked but the dialog itself when you call the .dialog('close') event...

Comment: @pixelbobby Added the #uploadModal html and the $(this).dialog('close') works properly, it just doesn't open the #uploadModal, thanks!

Comment: Thx.  Looking at your code it seems Christian's recommendation below would work. Make sure you mark it as the answer if that's the case :)

Comment: @Laxman13 Thanks for the suggestion, still learning the ropes of stackoverflow.

Answer (score 2):

Use the callback function that is executed when the dialog has finished his task.

```
[...]
'Upload Image': function() {
                // CLOSE 1 DIALOG AND OPEN ANOTHER
                $(this).dialog('close', function() {
                     $('#uploadModal').dialog('open');
                });

}, 
[...]
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but the solution didn't work. It closed the current dialog but did not open the #uploadModal. I tried it with a simple alert("TEST"); and it didn't work either.

Comment: does it say something in the debug console ? Another thing, have you declared the $(document).ready(function() { ... }); before all these instructions ?

Comment: Yep, i declared the $(function() { ... }); before everything. The #imageModal opens and closes perfectly, but does not open the #uploadModal on close and I have no errors in the debugger log related to this.

Comment: I really don't see why this isn't working. I've tested it in jsFiddle and it reacts the same as my production environment.

Comment: You cannot bind to the close event this way... you have to use the bind method as... $(this).bind("dialogClose", function ()...

Answer (score 1):

Hmm, have u change the order of close and open? Let´s say, first open the next dialog, then closes the first one?

1 - This;

```
// CLOSE 1 DIALOG AND OPEN ANOTHER
   $(this).dialog('close');
   $('#uploadModal').dialog('open');
```

2 - To:

```
// CLOSE 1 DIALOG AND OPEN ANOTHER
   $('#uploadModal').dialog('open');
   $(this).dialog('close');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(this).dialog('close');
$('#uploadModal').dialog('open');
```

This actually works fine for me (jquery 1.7 jquery-ui 1.8). The suggested answer only closes the dialog and doesn't open the new one.

Answer (score 0):

Try wrapping your "uploadModal" open call in a setTimeout.

```
'Upload Image': function() { 
    // CLOSE 1 DIALOG AND OPEN ANOTHER 
    $(this).dialog('close'); 
    setTimeout(function () {
        $('#uploadModal').dialog('open');
    }, 100);
},
```

You could also bind to the close event of the dialog via..

```
$("#uploadImage").bind("dialogClose", function () {
    // code goes here
});
```

but I think the first will work fine for what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, this has been up here for a bit. I was searching on how to fix the same issue. I posted up more code then needed so you can see whats going on. I used the name of the current dialog to close and the name of the new one to open. Works...

```
//============= User Modal ===============================//

$( "#dialog-message" ).dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    modal: true,
    resizable: false,
    width: 650,
    buttons: {
        Add: function() {
            $('#dialog-message').dialog( "close" );
            $('#dialog-message3').dialog( "open" );
        }
    }
});

$( "#opener" ).click(function() {
    $( "#dialog-message" ).dialog( "open" );
    return false;
}); 

//========== Add User Modal ============================ // 
$( "#dialog-message3" ).dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    modal: true,
    resizable: false,
    width: 250,
    buttons: {
        Save: function() {
            $( '#dialog-message3' ).dialog( "close" );
        }
    }
});
```